# Swipe until element visible in Android Espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a long vertical screen with data entry form. I need swipeUp (scroll down) this screen until one of form's field is displayed on screen.
I try use *swipeUp()* and *scrollTo()* ViewActions on the elements located higher on the screen, but it didn't help me, that these elements hiding from screen after swiping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idiomatic approach today would be to use [`RepeatActionUntilViewState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/action/RepeatActionUntilViewState). For example, the following would swipe up on an element with ID `largeElementId` up to 10 times until a view with text "Target text" is visible to the user:

```java
onView(withId(R.id.largeElementId)).perform(repeatedlyUntil(swipeUp(), 
        hasDescendant(withText("Target text")), 
        10));
```

Comment: do we have a single swipe mechanism ?

Comment: Yes, single swipe mechanism: onView(withId(R.id.largeElementId)).perform(swipeUp()); or change 10 to 1 in code above

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
boolean found = false;
int i = 0;
while (!found && i < MAX_SWIPES) {
    onView(withId(R.id.largeElementId)).perform(swipeUp());
    SystemClock.sleep(500);

    try {
        uiElementToSearch.check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        found = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // The search continues
    }
    i++;
}

if (!found) {
    Assert.fail("The element has not been found.");
}
```

Comment: I use "largeElement" (full-page recyclerView) and it's work! Thank you!